# Authorization in Azure Devops on premise error 401

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-devops

I'm trying to follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server?view=azure-devops#listen-for-http-post-requests.
But got only an 401 response code: "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."

```
versions:
azure-devops-node-api : 8.0.0
node : v10.15.3
```

Here is a code:

```
const azdev = require('azure-devops-node-api');

const collectionURL = "http://azure-devops-on-premise/DefaultCollection/Project";
const token = 'mypersonaltoken';

var authHandler = azdev.getPersonalAccessTokenHandler(token);

let connection = new azdev.WebApi(collectionURL, authHandler);

var azdevGit = connection.getGitApi().then( success => { console.log(success); }, error => { console.error(error); } );
```

Am I lost somewhere or it is a bug with azure-devops-node-api? Help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to send your token or login with username/password?

Comment: `set up the details for a connection to your account,` have you done that?

Comment: `const collectionURL = "http://azure-devops-on-premice/DefaultCollection/Project";` looks fishy. A collection URL would *not* contain a project. Try `http://azure-devops-on-premice/DefaultCollection/`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm trying to use token and I set it up in a code.

Comment: @daniel-mann I tried to change url with or without "/Project", but 401 response code still returned.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `collectionURL` should be in format `https://dev.azure.com/<your account>`, here the `<your account>` is your organization, please check it.

Secondly, have you checked whether the PAT is expired? the Expiration is 30 days by default.

Comment: Key thing in this question is "on premise" Azure DevOps, I think you talking about cloud Azure DevOps and it is different unfortunately. PAT is not expired i checked. I think there is a local problem with settings of Azure DevOps server (may be with IIS).